# Qtでシリアル通信 (connect関数がコンパイルエラー)

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Qtでシリアル通信しようとしており、クラスの中でイベントを受信したいのですが
`QObject::connect` 関数でシグナルとコールバック関数を結びつけるところでエラーになってしまいます
参考にしたいくつかのサンプルではフォームの中で `connect` 関数を使っていると上手く行くようなのですが
単独のクラス内で使うと上手く行かないみたいです

`connect` 関数の引数の考え方が間違っているようなのですが
引数は
クラスの実態
シグナル
送信元
コールバック
と思っていたのですが・・・

Qtはどうにもこうにも資料が少なくちょっと困ってます

---

**base.h**

```
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>

/**
 * @struct  シリアルポート設定構造体
 * @breif   シリアルポートの設定情報
 */
struct TSettingSerial{
    QSerialPort::BaudRate   rate;       //!<    ボーレート
    QSerialPort::DataBits   databits;   //!<    データビット
    QSerialPort::Parity     parity;     //!<    パリティ
    QSerialPort::StopBits   stopbits;   //!<    ストップビット
    QString                 strComName; //!<    シリアルポートのデバイス名称
};

/**
 * @brief   シリアルポートを操作するクラス
 * @details 送受信はこのクラスで全部やる
 */
class CSerialBase
{
public:
    //メソッド
    CSerialBase();  //!<    コンストラクタ
    ~CSerialBase(); //!<    デストラクタ
private :
    QSerialPort port;       //!<    シリアルポートオブジェクト
    void readdataWait();
public:
    bool open (TSettingSerial *setting);    //!<    ポートオープン
    void close();                           //!<    ポートクローズ
    bool write(const char*,qint64);         //!<ライト関数
};
```

**base.cpp**

```
#include "cserialbase.h"

#include    <QDebug>
#include    <qthread.h>

/**
 * @brief コンストラクタ
 */
CSerialBase::CSerialBase()
{
    //port = new  QSerialPort(this);
}

/**
 * @brief デストラクタ
 */
CSerialBase::~CSerialBase()
{
    //デストラクタが呼ばれることがあるかわからないが、取りあえずクローズ
    port.close();
}

void CSerialBase::readdataWait()
{
    int readedsize = 0;
    const int bufsize = 256;
    QByteArray buf;
    QString qs;

    while(true){        
        buf = port.readAll();
        if(buf.count() != 0){
           qDebug() << QString(qs.count());
        }
        QThread::msleep(10);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief           ポートオープン
 * @details         設定に従い、シリアルポートをオープンする
 * @param setting   シリアルポートの設定
 * @return          true=成功/失敗
 */
bool CSerialBase::open(TSettingSerial *setting)
{
    bool boRet = false;

    port.setPortName(setting->strComName);      //デバイス名称
    port.setBaudRate(setting->rate);            //ボーレート
    port.setDataBits(setting->databits);        //データビット
    port.setParity(setting->parity);            //パリティ
    port.setStopBits(setting->stopbits);        //ストップビット
    //オープン実行
    boRet = port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if(boRet == false){
        qDebug() << "ポートオープン失敗\n";
    }else{
        qDebug() << "ポートオープン成功\n";
        QObject::connect(&port,&QSerialPort::readyRead,this,&CSerialBase::readdataWait);    //★★★★ここがコンパイルエラー thisがまずそう
        // readしたときに関数を呼ぶ
        //readdataWait();
    }

    return boRet;
}

/**
 * @brief シリアルポートクローズ
 */
void CSerialBase::close()
{
    port.close();
}

/**
 * @brief   シリアルポート送信
 * @return  true=成功 / false=失敗
 */
bool CSerialBase::write(const char * data, qint64 len)
{
    qint64 iret = port.write(data, len);
    if(iret >= 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        qDebug() << "送信失敗:" << port.errorString();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Qt Serial Port - Reading data consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15103599/9014308), [C++ Threading Pattern for Qt serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25679153/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CSerialBase::readdataWait`をslotとして定義するのであれば、

1. `CSerialBase`クラスを`QObject`の派生クラスとして定義する。
2. クラス宣言の最初に`Q_OBJECT`マクロを記載する。
3. `readdataWait`メソッドを`slots`セクションで宣言する。

必要があると思います。

参考: Qt Documentation - Signals & Slots
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

具体的には、次のように`CSerialBase`クラスを宣言すればよいと思います。

```
class CSerialBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //メソッド
    CSerialBase();  //!<    コンストラクタ
    ~CSerialBase(); //!<    デストラクタ
private :
    QSerialPort port;       //!<    シリアルポートオブジェクト

public slots:
    void readdataWait();

public:
    bool open (TSettingSerial *setting);    //!<    ポートオープン
    void close();                           //!<    ポートクローズ
    bool write(const char*,qint64);         //!<ライト関数
};
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えていただいた方法と、コンストラクタの形式などを直したら上手く行きました。